# How can I return a value for a cell containing data from a number of cells?

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, vlookup

Using Excel/Numbers, I am wanting to use a formula which checks if a cell contains any of the data contained in a number of other cells, if if it does I want to return a custom value or write out another formula, if it does, I want it to retune "n/a"

**Column A** (The options)

- DNS
- Hosting
- Mapping
- No Appointment
- Reference

**Column B** (The column containing the formula)

**Column C** (The criteria to search for)

- DNS
- Hosting
- Mapping
- No Appointment
- Reference

Whilst the syntax is wrong, I'm looking to achieve this:

*If A2 contains any of the data from column B then return "Cakes" if not return "N/A*"

*If A3 contains any of the data from column B then return "Cakes" if not return "N/A*"

etc. etc.

I've tried using

```
=IF(LOOKUP(C2,E$2:E$5,TRUE)=TRUE,"CAKES","N/A")
```

The correct output was obtained on the first cell alone but the formula output errors for all other cells.

Comment: Not sure how this would help if it doesn't work, but I've tried using

IF(LOOKUP(C2,E$2:E$5,TRUE)=TRUE,"CAKES","N/A") The correct output was obtained on the first cell alone but the formula output errors for all other cells

Comment: @JessicaHoward: please put that in your question, not a comment. Questions can be edited using the "edit" link. Did it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following formula, I have achieved what I was wanting to do, but I welcome additional formula or any tidier ways of achieving the same goal

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$50,B$2:B$5)=1,"CAKES","N/A")
```